# HSQLDB user lacks privilege or object not found error when making select statements in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, junit, hsqldb

I have gone through Stack overflow existing scenarios of why we are getting this error.
I have just simple person class and a service for which I am writing a test case using embedded database. There is no problem in the code but it is not creating database.

Comment: Some code here to understand might help....

Comment: Adding the following in properties file help resolved the issue.:
spring.jpa.database=hsql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:person
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=HSQL

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and when I started to read the logs, I saw that, it couldn't create a table, because one of my string fields was annotated with @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT").

So, most of the cases it can't create/select from a table, not because  you don't have access to it. Just read your logs, and see what is the problem with creating/selection the table.